# What does `y` stand for in Perl

Tags: perl

I have found the following piece of Perl code online:

```
y/a-z//s
```

I looked in the docs to see what it does, but I didn't find anything about it. What does the `y` stand for here?

The full code:

```
($_='jjjuuusssttt annootthheer
     pppeeerrrlll haaaccckkeer')=~y/a-z//s;print;
```

Comment: `y` aka `tr` -- transliterate.

Comment: @Dharman, actually, you have not a regex...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators):

> tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr
>   y/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr
>   Transliterates all occurrences of the characters found in the search list with the corresponding character in the replacement list.
>
> For sed devotees, y is provided as a synonym for tr.
>
> Options:
>
> - c   Complement the SEARCHLIST.
> - d   Delete found but unreplaced characters.
> - s   Squash duplicate replaced characters.
> - r   Return the modified string and leave the original string untouched.
>
> If the REPLACEMENTLIST is empty, the SEARCHLIST is replicated.

Comment: good, but I like to know about keys of that operator :) please, provide some explanation like "s means single_character", so it removes all duplicates :)

Comment: @gaussblurinc All of them are explained in that documentation. Copied anyway.

Comment: @LeeDuhem, I know, but ... this question could not exists if OP knew about documentation

Comment: @gaussblurinc That is exactly why I said "According to `perlop`" and included that link in my answer :-)